# Местоименное наречие "сколько"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Рассмотрим два таких предложения: "Врач предписал ему сколько что кушать" и "Врач  предписал ему сколько чего  кушать". Разъясните, пожалуйста, смысловое различие между двумя этими предложениями.

Comment: Начнём с того, что слово "кушать" с грамотной речью вообще несовместимо, [подробнее](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/trudnosti?id=36_143&layout=item).

Comment: @freim начнем с того, что даже ваш источник (авторитетность которого и без того под большим вопросом) не столь категоричен.

Comment: @behemothus, да достало уже это слово в современной литературе. Когда употребляется взрослым человеком в отношении взрослого человека. Так-то оно, конечно, уместно в некоторых случаях, но именно что в некоторых. P.S. Ну уничтожьте меня ссылкой на авторитетный источник, что ли. Насчёт которого никаких сомнений нет.

Comment: А зачем? Это ваши проблемы давать ссылки на источники. Смысл моего замечания не в том, что авторитетность неподписанного источника невысока, а в том, что даже там нет столь категорических суждений.

Comment: @behemothus, ну а смысл моего замечания в том, что оба приведённых варианта грамотными не являются. У вас есть возражения насчёт этого?

Comment: @freim Согласен. Но спрашивают разницу в значениях.

Comment: @oleedd, и какой смысл разбирать разницу значений двух безграмотных вариантов? А метка при этом, напомню: "грамотная речь". Здесь надо полностью переработать предложение, чтобы привести его к чему-то нормальному.

Comment: @freim Автору это, скорее всего, не нужно. Тогда бы спросил, как правильно. Интересует разница в смысле. Но переработать не помешает.

Comment: *У вас есть возражения насчёт этого?* - есть. Вы неправы.

Answer (score 0):

Верно только `сколько чего`. После `сколько` должно быть склонение.

`Чего` - это и есть склонение слова `что`. Смысл тот же, так как это одно и тоже слово.

Answer (score 0):

> Разъясните, пожалуйста, смысленное различие между двумя этими предложениями

Разницы здесь нет - за исключением того, что второй вариант "сколько что" не соответствует литературной норме. 
Разбираться тут долго, начать придется с того, какая вообще грамматическая роль у "сколько" и "чего/что". В данном случае это союзные слова, присоединяющие придаточное.
По отдельности возможно и "прописал, сколько кушать", и "прописал, чего кушать" и "предписал, что кушать", более того, "чего кушать" - разговорный, на грани просторечия, вариант.
То есть "что кушать" и "сколько кушать" вполне возможно.
А вот соединить их вместе в качестве однородных не получается, иначе как через союз "Предписал, сколько и что кушать". Почему? Да потому, что "сколько" само по себе требует родительного падежа. И члены не воспринимаются как однородные. К тому же однородность требовала бы запятой - *"прописал, сколько, что кушать"* - а это вообще зрительно не воспринимается. Итак, вариант "Сколько что" исключается.

Что же происходит в случае "прописал, сколько чего"? Казалось бы, здесь возникают те же проблемы. Но нет, "чего" здесь является не союзным словом, а зависимым от "сколько" - "сколько воды, деталей, времени" - ***сколько чего***. Хотя смысл от этого не меняется.

Таким образом, вариант "предписал, сколько чего" возможен.
Должен, впрочем, заметить, что стилистически "предписал" и "кушать" не очень согласуются.
Но это уже отдельный разговор, который в данной теме лучше не понимать.

Comment: А слово `смысленное` никто не прокомментировал ещё? Я такого слова не знаю (хотя и понимаю), правильно: *смысловое различие*.

Comment: @tum_ Тут не исправляют ошибки в вопросе. Очевидно, что там `смысловое`. Хотя в словарях есть слово `смысленный`, но оно сюда не подходит.

Answer (score -1):

Ответ исключительно о теоретической разнице в смысле между "сколько что кушать" и "сколько чего кушать".

`Сколько чего кушать` - обозначает то, сколько конкретно порций, штук, грамм съедать.

Второй вариант теоретически может существовать только при указании на время.

`Сколько что кушать` - кушать яблоко 2 минуты, обедать 15 минут.

Доктор такое предписывать не будет. Хотя есть закономерность: чем дольше ешь, тем больше съешь. А любой врач против переедания.

В таком варианте `сколько` иногда используется. Например: сколько туда ехать?